# node.js application starts timing out after a certain period of time

Tags: heroku

Developing a web app with javascript/express/node. On my local machine and Heroku, after running for a short period of time (~5 mins), I have to restart the server or it never responds to requests. I have no idea what could be causing this. Has anyone dealt with something like this before?

```
2014-02-10T01:25:29.935130+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 304 281ms
2014-02-10T01:25:29.936342+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=wwwcom request_id=8d2cd623-c379-4e6a-8b30-1021dd2f5d18 fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms      service=284ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-02-10T01:25:30.096768+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/css/style.css host=wwwcom request_id=953f1c0c-65ce-4ac7-bfc5-04d5bec2791a fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-02-10T01:24:10.997307+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/img/money.jpg host=wwwcom request_id=b1eb7f92-98ae-466d-8e03-a7539215936a fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-02-10T01:25:30.171105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/img/money.jpg host=wwwcom request_id=fd9244d0-22eb-4e28-ac81-b820bcab753b fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=16ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-02-10T01:27:58.989371+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/ host=wwwcom request_id=ddcb47a6-b250-49ea-8ba8-9c9da4c41c91 fwd="" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
2014-02-10T01:27:58.997153+00:00 app[web.1]: GET / 200 30003ms
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be good to start [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout), especially the *Debugging request timeouts* section could be of help:

**Debugging request timeouts**

One cause of request timeouts is an infinite loop in the code. Test locally (perhaps with a copy of the production database pulled down with pgbackups) and see if you can replicate the problem and fix the bug. Another possibility is that you are trying to do some sort of long-running task inside your web process, such as:

- Sending an email
- Accessing a remote API (posting to Twitter, querying Flickr, etc.)
- Web scraping / crawling
- Rendering an image or PDF
- Heavy computation (computing a fibonacci sequence, etc.)
- Heavy database usage (slow or numerous queries, N+1 queries)

If so, you should move this heavy lifting into a background job which can run asynchronously from your web request. See background workers for details.

Comment: thanks i did see that while searching, now going to be looking into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770284/node-js-requests-randomly-begin-to-hang-and-wont-clear-until-server-restart